# Show Workbench output as MySQL table format

Tags: mysql-workbench

so

```
+----------+-------------+----------------+----------------------+
| actor_id | first_name  | last_name      | last_update          |
+----------+-------------+----------------+----------------------+
|        1 | PENELOPE    | GUINESS        | 2006-02-15 4:34:33   |
|        2 | NICK        | WAHLBERG       | 2006-02-15 4:34:33   |
|        3 | ED          | CHASE          | 2006-02-15 4:34:33   |
+----------+-------------+----------------+----------------------+
```

instead of

[image]

Edit for clarity:
I want the actual text output since I don't have access to the DB via command line and am currently only working with workbench.

Right-clicking the output on workbench only allows you to grab the data as CSV or TSV which doesn't look as nice when posted on chats like slack, or comment systems like Jira.

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: The actual format of the output. I was wondering if Workbench supports outputting the data in MySQL Table format (ie. in plain text) instead of the UI table. I don't have access to the DB via command line.

Comment: You can copy the data out in a text format from the grid as well.

Comment: Yeah but like I said it doesn't have the option to copy it in that specific text format. I was really thinking this would be an option on Workbench, I guess not.

Comment: Then download the cli from mysql's website and use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get pure text output by running your query via another menu entry/hot key:

[image]

which will give you output like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Cannot for the life of me find this anywhere on Workbench docs.